# Array sorter. Output error

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Ive written an array sort using the examples i found on this site. However my code isnt compiling right. Instead of storing the first value, it just stores the integer 0 and repeats it. I cant seem to find whats wrong with it, but i suspect it to be somewhere in my for loop.

```
/**
* @author angu2548
* XXX 310255325
*/
public class Sorter {

    public int[] sortArray(String[] args) {
        int [] numbers = new int [args.length];

        //Turning it into an int [] array
        for (int i= 0; i > args.length; i++){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            numbers[i] = x;
        }

        //Insertion sort
        for(int j = 1; j < numbers.length; j++){
            int temp = numbers[j];
            int i = j -1;

            while (i  > 0 && numbers[i] > temp){
                numbers[i + 1] = numbers[i];
                i--;            
            }
            numbers[i + 1] = temp;
            //System.out.println("got to here");
        }
        return numbers;
    }       

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Sorter sort = new Sorter();
        int[] result = sort.sortArray(args); 
        if(result != null && result.length > 0){
            System.out.print("[" + result[0]);
            for(int i=1; i<result.length; ++i){
                System.out.print(", " + result[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] Even though my values are
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 5 4 3]

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake in the loop condition:

```
for (int i= 0; i > args.length; i++)
```

will prevent the loop from running, so `numbers` never gets initialized with the right elements. It should be

```
for (int i= 0; i < args.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `'>'` with `'<'` in the following line:

```
for (int i= 0; i > args.length; i++)
```

Comment: Opps, the same answer that @Peter Torok